# One for the money, two for the show

Tags: expressions

What does the expression

> [x] for the money

mean?

I remember hearing the topic title in a rap song (can’t remember which, might be Eminem), and there seem to be movies named after this pattern: *[Two For the Money](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417217/)* with Al Pacino and *[One For the Money](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1598828/)*, an upcoming comedy.

*[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/)* does not seem to know this expression, neither does *[dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/)* give a proper translation.

What does it mean and where does it come from?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My impression is that

> One for the money. Two for the show. Three to make ready. And four to go.

(or "*three to get ready*" in contemporary English) is something that children say when they start a race (the running starting on "go"). Anyway, it's appears in [this 1872 book](http://books.google.com/books?id=FlVIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22one+for+the+money%22+%22two+for%22&hl=en&ei=XHV7TrayN4Hs0gHhw5zfAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22one%20for%20the%20money%22%20%22two%20for%22&f=false), (it's not a race here, but FumbleFingers has found another 1872 citation where it is used for a race).

I would assume that "the money" refers to the prize for winning, and "the show" to the spectacle of the race. Generally, a children's race won't have either of these (unlike, say a professional horse race), but it doesn't hurt to pretend.

Comment: Here's a rather morbid [1837 instance](http://books.google.com/books?id=vNsRAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA468&dq=%22three+to+make+ready%22&hl=en&ei=Pdd7TuXKNcWDtgecvr0E&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22three%20to%20make%20ready%22&f=false).

Comment: Having also noted that @Callithumpian's instance starts with *One to get ready*, I reckon it's a definitely a kids' ditty. Maybe originally said while doing something collective *other* than having a race. Like throwing one of their number in a pool, for example. I'm thinking something like that because there would maybe be a "practice swing" (*one get ready, two do a 'practice/show' swing*), then the real *three get ready, four* **go!** as they toss someone in the water (or whatever).

Answer (score 8):

I first heard it in [Blue Suede Shoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Suede_Shoes) written by Carl Perkins in 1955 (decades before Eminem was even born), and popularised by Elvis Presley a year later. But all credit to @Peter Shor for pointing out that it was around a very long time before that. I found a different instance to Peter, but they're both [from 1872](http://books.google.com/books?id=OR5AAAAAYAAJ&q=%22two%20for%20the%20show%22&dq=%22two%20for%20the%20show%22&hl=en&ei=nHl7TuedJqiu0QXTwsWjAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwADgK).

Possibly it's an allusion to the idea that the performer makes *one* (the first) effort because he's getting paid for it, and *two* (the second) because he just likes performing. Or perhaps it's *one for the performer's money*, and *two for the share going to the venue*. After that it's just counting in to the start of the main action.

It was originally *three to make ready*, but that sounds a bit dated to our ears. Today it's invariably *three to get ready* except for the title of an episode in the 60s TV series [My Favorite Martian](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0654565/).

Comment: I'll leave this answer here because I don't want the only modern reference on this page to be Eminem, but I'm rooting for @Peter Shor's take on it now. Probably nothing to do with money or even a performance, originally.

Answer (score 5):

The The Oxford Dictionary of Nursery Rhymes and [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/58/messages/1811.html) cite a horse race poem that is likely the source of the phrase.  In horse racing, the winners are termed:

1. Win
2. Place
3. Show

The omission of "place" is noted in The Phrase Finder.  This is likely poetic license, to make a short rhyme, used to start a race or event.

Exerpt from The Phrase Finder post:

> In "The Annotated Mother Goose" p 259 the following rhyme is included:
>
> One to make ready
>
> And two to prepare
>
> good luck to the rider
>
> And away goes the mare.

Answer (score 1):

In ‘Blue Suede Shoes’, Elvis Presley sang:

> Well, it's one for the money, / Two for the show, / Three to get ready, /
>   Now go, cat, go.

I’m not sure it means very much at all.

Comment: It's [much, much older](http://books.google.com/books?id=FlVIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22one+for+the+money%22+%22two+for%22&hl=en&ei=XHV7TrayN4Hs0gHhw5zfAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22one%20for%20the%20money%22%20%22two%20for%22&f=false) than that (the link is to an 1872 book). "One for the money. Two for the show. Three to get ready. And four to go."

Comment: @Peter Shor: Lawks! I'd no idea! Excuse me while I go and tinker with my answer...

Comment: Maybe I should just write an answer.