# 1 for the money and 2 for the show

Tags: slang

I keep hearing "I say 1 for the money and 2 for the show" (or variants of it) in various songs (rap specifically though I have heard it in other songs) . Can anyone tell me why it is used so much and where did it come from? Thanks. (If this helps, I hear it mainly in K-rap and I think it has something to do with "Show Me The Money")

Comment: The rappers probably got it from Elvis. And Elvis got it from an old childrens' rhyme. [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42936/one-for-the-money-two-for-the-show).

Comment: Whatever else, I suspect that has nothing at all to do with *Show me the money* which phrase I personally have only ever heard from Tom Cruise in *Jerry Maguire* which movie seemed to have no point other than to measure how loudly someone could shout *Show me the money*